# C++ SFINAE to determine the number of function arguments (C++17)

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I created a metafunction using SFINAE to determine the number of arguments of a function at compile time. It works fine with gcc when used with with function objects, but not with lambda closures, I don't understand why. The metafunction is here below

```
template < typename T >
int val (T &&){return 0;};

template <int N, typename Functor>
struct has_args {

  template <typename F , int ... Args>
  static auto test(F, decltype(val(std::declval<F>()( Args ... ))), std::integer_sequence<int, Args ...>){
          return std::true_type{};
      };

  template <typename F, typename Val, typename Seq>
  static auto test(F, Val, Seq){
          return std::false_type{};
      };

  using type =  decltype (test(std::declval<Functor>(), 0, std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>()));
};
```

and here is how it should behave

```
struct func{
    template<typename T>
    int operator()(T){}
};
int main(){

  auto lambda0 = [](auto arg){};

  static_assert(has_arg<1, func>::type::value==true, "error");
  //static_assert(has_arg<1, decltype(lambda0)>::type::value==true, "error"); // Assertion fails!
}
```

The full code (with few more examples) is in this git repo: https://github.com/crosetto/has_args/blob/main/number_of_arguments.cpp

Does anybody have an explanation of why this doesn't work with lambdas?

Comment: `func` vs `funct` ? is this a typo? Please make sure the code you post does reproduce the issue you describe, as posted its an error (but not the one the question is about)

Comment: Lambda has no `return` statement. So return type is `void`. How do you want to match `void` with type of `0` what is int. With `return int{}` works fine.

Comment: Or `decltype(val(std::declval<Derived>()( Args ... )), void(), 42)`.

Comment: thanks @rafix07 , that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment by @rafix07, the issue here is that the lambda is returning void, so it's signature is not matched in the first definition of `test`, and falls back to the other overload. One fix is to apply a comma operator to the argument of `val`, i.e. changing

```
static auto test(F, decltype(val(std::declval<F>()( Args ... ))), std::integer_sequence<int, Args ...>)
```

into

```
static auto test(F, decltype(val((std::declval<F>()( Args ... ),0))), std::integer_sequence<int, Args ...>)
```

or, as pointed out by @Jarod42 in the comments, `val` is unnecessary, and one can write:

```
static auto test(F, decltype(((std::declval<F>()( Args ... ),void(),0))), std::integer_sequence<int, Args ...>)
```

Note that the function body gets parsed, and any use of the arguments which wouldn't compile with integers results in a compiler error. I think this cannot be worked around in a generic way (one can use a fake type other than int though, and make it satisfy the required API).

Comment: I would use `val(.., void(), 0)` (or directly (`.., void(), 0`)) to handle evil possible overload of operator comma.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @Jarold42 I think in your comment you miss an extra parenthesis, ```val((..., void(), 0))```, right?. It still has a problem which I guess can't be fixed: the function body gets parsed, and any use of the arguments which wouldn't compile with integers results in a compiler error.

Comment: Yes, indeed. but as I also try to underline, `val` is unneeded. it is a workaround try from OP which doesn't handle `void` return type. Comma operator does the workaround job.

Comment: sure, I'll add your remark to the answer as well